# Confused about isolating an argument from a fraction and computing a value for it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fourier-analysis

Ok so if I have a fraction which looks as follows

$$\frac{8π}{N + 1}$$

How could I calculate N on its own?

The above fraction is the mainlobe width formula for a Hamming window and I'm trying to find out how much terms are required (N) for a filter using a Hamming window

solution from someone anonymous (which I do not comprehend)

$$\frac{8π}{N+1} = 0.5 * \frac{\pi}{8}   N = 8*16 -1= 127$$

the 0.5 multiplication is just put in there so it only uses half the mainlobe (one side only)

maybe you can help me to understand clearly how this person has done this calculation

Comment: You can't, unless this ratio is supposed to mean something (i.e. is equal to some known quantity).

Comment: So far, this is just an expression of a fraction.  Is there another part that creates an equality or inequality to bound the value of $N$?

Comment: I've changed the tags to the very odd combination of [tag:algebra-precalculus] and [tag:fourier-analysis], since neither [tag:linear-algebra] nor [tag:filters] fits this question. "Filter," in mathematics, means something different than in signal processing.

Comment: I have the solution already which was written by somebody else but the reason why I wanted to ask the question is because I did not understand it. I will edit the answer with the solution I found, done by somebody else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think many of us are having trouble understanding your question, but it seems that you are asking the following:  I know that $\frac{8 \pi}{N+1} = \frac{\pi}{16}$.  How do I determine the value of $N$?

If that is the question, then this is really a matter of high school algebra.

First, notice that both sides of the equation have a $\pi$ in them, so that can be cancelled.

Next, multiply both sides of the equation by 16.

At this point the equation reads $\frac{128}{N+1} = 1$.  From this it follows that $N+1=128$, so $N=127$.

Regarding the "anonynmous solution from someone that you do not understand":  Don't ever get help from that person again.  He or she seems to know, sort of, how to solve equations, but does not know what an equals sign means; what is written down is a string of operations that amount to gibberish, with the right answer at the end.

Comment: yes, I can easily solve this problem once I know what this equation validates to, but I did not know that it was equal to PI/16

Comment: I'm just accepting this as the answer because you pointed out the fact. Do you happen to know if there are any on-line sources on this subject of Filter Windows - for example, how did you know that it equals PI/16?

Comment: I had no idea it was equal to $\pi/16$, I got it from *you*.

Comment: Oh, Well I guess it logically must equal to π/16 or else π/32 if 0.5 is being multiplied to get the answer of 128, I'm finding it hard to find information on this niche area..

Answer (score 2):

If you have the value of this fraction, say $x$, then
$$x = \frac{8\pi}{N+1}$$
thus
$$N+1 = \frac{8\pi}{x}$$
and so
$$N = \frac{8\pi}{x} - 1$$

Comment: that does make things more clear. If you would look at my question again, I made an edit which has the solution written by an anonymous person, but I do not understand how he did the math for it